# How to read the time from JSpinner using the Event ChangeListener() and Print it on the Console?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I want help to read the time from the JSpinner using the event ChangeListener. **The problem is that the time is printed twice when I spin with one step**.
 The Output, when I run the below code within the main program, is 
00:00, 01:00 for a single spin up.
 Could you help me to know the reason and how it could be fixed to print only one value when I spin up or down? thanks ..see Example

```
public class SpinnerTest {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                SpinnerTest window = new SpinnerTest();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public SpinnerTest() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    JPanel groupLayoutPanel = new JPanel();

    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(1591563600775L), null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            JSpinner spinner = (JSpinner)e.getSource();
            Date sdate= (Date)spinner.getValue();
            String pattern = "HH:mm";
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            String date = simpleDateFormat.format(sdate);
            System.out.println(date);

        }
    });
    JSpinner.DateEditor de= new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner,"HH:mm");
    spinner.setEditor(de);

    GroupLayout grouplayout= new GroupLayout(groupLayoutPanel);
    grouplayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        grouplayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(grouplayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(83)
                .addComponent(spinner, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(321, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    grouplayout.setVerticalGroup(
        grouplayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(grouplayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(25)
                .addComponent(spinner, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(216, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    groupLayoutPanel.setLayout(grouplayout);
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setContentPane(groupLayoutPanel);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

}

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: The output that i got from the code is 00:00 and 01:00 for one single spin up

Comment: Whatever .. When is the MRE / SSCCE due to be added to the question?

Comment: I added an example. I wish it will help

Answer (score 1):

> Could you help me to know the reason and how it could be fixed to print only one value when I spin up or down

You need to check the `getValueIsAdjusting()` property of the state listener to determine if the adjustment has finished.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a ChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html) for more information and examples.

Edit:

The double event is only generated the first time a spinner button is clicked.

Here is a workaround that seems to work. I set the editor and commit the editor before adding the ChangeListener:

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(1591563600775L), null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
JSpinner.DateEditor de= new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner,"HH:mm");
spinner.setEditor(de);

try
{
    spinner.commitEdit();
}
catch(Exception e) {}

spinner.addChangeListener(…);
```

Comment: getValueIsAdjusting() is working with JSlider not JSpinner

Comment: as per my tries to find out why the JSpinner acting like that i found one interesting fact. if you trying to set the JSpinner value into another component like JLable or JtextFiled the value will be printed as one value per spin up or down but if you tried to print it using System.out.println on Console it will print twice per spin up or down...

Comment: *getValueIsAdjusting() is working with JSlider not JSpinner* - good point. *...like JLable or JtextFiled the value will be printed as one value* - that is because the setText() method executes so fast you only ever see the last value displayed.

Comment: So is there any reason behind why the message is displayed twice on console?

Comment: can anyone explain to me what is the benefit of setCommitsOnValidEdit for DefaultFormatter ?

Comment: Just noticed that it only happens the first time you click on a spinner button. After that the event is only generated once. Don't know why. There must be some internal value that is not set in the model. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Spinners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html). The SpinnerDemo3 does not have this problem when you click on the "Month", but it does have the same behaviour when you click on "Another Date". So there is something about the data model that appears to cause the inconsistency.

Comment: Hi Camickr. did you trySpinnerDemo3 to print even the month? because I tried it and did the same behavior print twice on the console.

Comment: @MaxPody I added: `spinner.addChangeListener((e) -> System.out.println(e) );` to both the  "month" and "year" spinners. I normally only see one event. However, when you start the demo and click the down button you will see two events because the month/year spinners are linked. When the month goes from January to December, the year decreases by one so two events are generated one for the change in month and one for the change in year. If you click down again I only see one event.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you change the value of the `JSpinner`, two change events are fired.

The first change event is because the initial value of the model is set as the value of the editor. That's why the first value printed is the initial value of the model.

The second change event is fired because the value is changed due to the user action. Hence the second value printed is the new value that results from the user change.

That's why the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258206/how-to-read-the-time-from-jspinner-using-the-event-changelistener-and-print-it/62262736#62262736) from *camickr* works. He forces the first change event to fire by calling method `commitEdit()` before adding the `ChangeListener` to the `JSpinner`. So when the user changes the spinner value the first time, only the second change event fires.

If you add the `ChangeListener` before calling method `commitEdit()`, then when the GUI is first displayed, you will see the initial value printed before actually interacting with the `JSpinner`.